# Multiple User Section [more than one page]

Tags: php, session, redirect, header, location

I'm starting a session and redirect after successful login to a home.php

now my question is how can i let access the users more pages. i thought about:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['user_session'])!="")
    {
        header("Location: home.php");
        header("Location: home2.php")
    }

    ?>
```

this page should only useable to the users.
 **First the user should be redirected to home.php and then the user should get access to another page like home2.php but a non-user shouldn't get access to this page.**
When the user is at home.php i thought about a simple `<a></a>` redirect with html to home2.php

Comment: Create a $isuser or $loggedin variable and set it to true when a user logs in then just put an if statement around the <a></a> so only logged in users will see the link

Comment: is there no way to do this with the header() function

Comment: header() is essentially a redirection. on login you can use header("Location: home.php"); to redirect (automatically load) them to the home.php page however if you want them (and only logged in users) to have access from home.php to home2.php then you will need to check the user is logged in and use an if statement around the <a></a> tags.

Comment: okay thanx mate i'll try

Comment: check http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL. Whilst some of it could be improved, the login check function would probably serve you perfectly. If you are going to follow that tutorial word for word, change the SHA512 to the phps built in hashing functions

Comment: i solved my problem with a session checking;) but thanxs either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a session and make an `<a></a>` Tag that only registered useres can see. 
You have to `session_start()` in every site and Theo redirect if the User is already logged in